# write a bean to the title attribute of an element in a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, attributes, javabeans, title

I have a jsp page that is calling a action form my problem is how do I get the data in each row to not only get written to be the bean but also put it in the title attribute?

```
    <td>
                    <bean:write name="data" property="aName" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <bean:write name="data" property="aSport" />
                </td>
          <td>
                <html:checkbox indexed="true" name="sportForm" property="assignSport"
         title="<%=sporttForm.getaName %><%=sporttForm.getaSport %>" />
                </td>
```

I would like the title when the checkbox is hovered over to be something like: John Smith - Football

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `alt` attribute, rather than `title`. So,

```
<html:checkbox indexed="true" name="sportForm" property="assignSport"  alt="<%=sporttForm.getaName %><%=sporttForm.getaSport %>" />
```

Comment: all I get is sporttForm.getaName cannot be resolved or is not a field and the same message for sporttForm.getaSport

Comment: So, at the point the JSP is generated, do you know the values that are to be updated? If so, then you should use `data.aName` and `data.aSport`. If you want it to happen dynamically when things change on your page, you will have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The jsp:attribute element allows you to define the value of a tag attribute in the body of an XML element instead of in the value of an XML attribute.

JSP Syntax

XML Syntax
Same as JSP syntax.

Examples
The following template page uses jsp:attribute, which uses the output of fmt:message to set the value of the value attribute of tt:parameter:

...

```
  <tt:screen id="/bookcatalog">
    <tt:parameter name="title" direct="true">
      <jsp:attribute name="value" >
         <fmt:message key="TitleBookCatalog"/>
      </jsp:attribute>
   </tt:parameter>
```

...

```
</tt:screen>
```

...

Source:
http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2014.html